# Spring Boot Scheduler not triggered at Scheduled Time

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I Schedule a Job for an email Trigger with Cron Expression in Application Properties, email is not trigger and each Time when I stop the Tomcat and reconfigure the Time it is triggering the job.

Comment: Please share the configuration you have used in your application.

Comment: Please share your code. It seems you are missing some configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify you have configuration correctly. And trigger job for particular time you have to have method level configuration also as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 0 * ?")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {

//Email trigger at 12 clock 
}
}
```

Comment: And add you Cron job configuration and your spring boot version if you have any further clarification.